# Most efficient way to apply custom sort order to an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a string array that is similar to:

```
[module-src1, module-src2, module-src3, ..., source1, source2, source3, ...]
```

I want to reorder this array to be:

```
[source1, source2, source3, ..., module-src1, module-src2, module-src3, ...]
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in Java?

I thought about having 2 queues to store each, but that seems overly complicated and I am hoping to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: how do you define efficient?  order of magnitude, or your time?

Comment: something involving Arrays.sort and comparators

Comment: @La-comadreja probably the least lines possible?

Comment: [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of doing it is by having your own class like

```
public class Source implements Comparable<Source> {
    private String name;
    public Source(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Source another) {
        //do whatever sorting you want here
        //for example:
        if(name.subString(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("module") &&
                another.getName().subString(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("module"){
            //both start with module, so alphabetize
            return name.compareTo(another.getName());
        } else if(name.subString(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("module") &&
                !another.getName().subString(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("module"){
            //only this one starts with "module", the other one comes first
             return -1;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

hopefully you get the gist with that.

Once you have all those objects in an `ArrayList` or something, just do `Collections.sort(myArray)` and it should sort it in the order you want

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some assumptions about your input (that is, you have to assume that all strings in your array are formatted either "module-"- or "source"-prefixed). If that's the case, then you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] strings = new String[]{"module-src1","module-src2",
            "module-src3","source1","source2","source3"};
    Arrays.sort(strings,new ModSrcComparator());
    for(String s : strings) System.out.print(s+" ");
    System.out.println();
}

private static class ModSrcComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if(!s1.contains("-") && s2.contains("-")) return -1;
        else if(s1.contains("-") && !s2.contains("-")) return 1;
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot about `Comparator` (－‸ლ)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a String array with a minimal number of lines of code:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArray))
Collections.sort(myList);
myArray = myList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

I'd suggest using a List instead of an array, which brings this down to a single line of code:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

Comment: Wouldn't sort make it alphabetical order? My initial array is already in alphabetical order, I need to move sources to the front of modules while keeping the alphabetical order of sources and alphabetical order of modules.

Comment: My bad. You'd have to do Epicblood's answer first, to have a custom sort order, then do this. Or you can use a Comparator instead of implementing Comparable...